# multi-module maven spring boot application stops immediately after running

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I'm creating a multi-module spring boot application using maven in IntelliJ. When I run it using IntelliJ, everything works fine. But when I use maven package (IntelliJ maven plugin), the pom file in root of project, does not work. But when I use jar file from `gateway` module, it has all the components. But two things:

- It does not read my `application.properties` file
- It starts the project and `Started MyappGatewayApplication in 5.009 seconds (JVM running for 5.257)` message appears, but immediately `SpringApplicationShutdownHook` triggers and stops the application.

Here are my pom.xml files (parent, gateway, service and util modules) consecutively:

//parent pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myapp</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.mysite.gateway.MyappGatewayApplication</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mysite.gateway.myappGatewayApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov</groupId>
        <artifactId>bucket4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20220924</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<modules>
    <module>myapp-gateway</module>
    <module>myapp-service</module>
    <module>myapp-util</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

//gateway module pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp-gateway</artifactId>
<version>3</version>
<name>myapp-gateway</name>
<description>myapp Gateway Module</description>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-service</artifactId>
        <version>3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-util</artifactId>
        <version>3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

//service module pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp-service</artifactId>
<version>3</version>
<name>myapp-service</name>
<description>myapp Service Module</description>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-util</artifactId>
        <version>3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

//util module pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-util</artifactId>
    <version>3</version>
    <name>myapp-util</name>
    <description>myapp Utility Module</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: your problem is likely unrelated to maven, but alive `Thread`s. make sure you have started non-daemon threads in your module, otherwise SpringBoot app dies immediately after the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. The problem was because of an unused and extra dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

after removing this dependency, everything worked correctly. It seems this dependency, didn't let Tomcat to be launched after running with `java -jar`.

Thanks